# Color coding calendars for invitees

Tags: google-calendar

Every time I send an invite, it shows up as the default color on the recipients calendar.  Although I can easily color code the event on my end, how can I make it so the recipient receives the same color so he can easily differentiate between work and personal once accepting the invite and adding it to his calendar?

Comment: I would really **not** like you to send me a calendar invitation and override the default color. I have several calendars that I've color-coded for myself. How do you know the color you choose doesn't match something I've chosen for a different calendar. Google is right not to offer this option.

Comment: Well thank goodness I'm not sending it to you.  However, my recipient is asking me to do this so I have to ask.  Your opinion is appreciated, but I just need to know if it possible and, if so, how it can be done.  BTW, I know what color he prefers;)  I'm sure Google thanks you for your thoughts.

Comment: No, it's not possible.